# Max execution time error with stream_body() in wp-includes/class-http.php

Tags: import

I am trying to importing the theme-unit-test xml file from wordpress.org to my own wordpress(4.0) through import section. This is my php.ini setting

[image]

But still get the max execution time limit error. I tried one more way with .htaccess to my worpdress site.

```
php_value max_execution_time 3000
```

But it is also not working. This is the exact error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\omnipress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1498
```

Then i decided to go into the core file and checked the line has the following method:

```
private function stream_body( $handle, $data ) {
    $data_length = strlen( $data );

    if ( $this->max_body_length && ( strlen( $this->body ) + $data_length ) > $this->max_body_length )
        $data = substr( $data, 0, ( $this->max_body_length - $data_length ) );

    if ( $this->stream_handle ) {
        $bytes_written = fwrite( $this->stream_handle, $data );
    } else {
        $this->body .= $data;
        $bytes_written = $data_length;
    }

    // Upon event of this function returning less than strlen( $data ) curl will error with CURLE_WRITE_ERROR.
    return $bytes_written;
}
```

And this method is called in the following CURL request:

```
if ( true === $r['blocking'] ) {
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array( $this, 'stream_headers' ) );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, array( $this, 'stream_body' ) );
    }
```

This CURL request has the connection timeout parameter, that i set to 0 (means unlimited timeout)

```
$timeout = (int) ceil( 0 );
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
```

But still it is not working :(
Please give me the right direction to achieve this, what i have missed. This is the link of test data that i want to import into my wordpress.
https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml

Comment: Had you tried choosing to skip importing media? As far as I remember there are sometimes quirks with network timeouts and those images hosted on wordpress com.

Comment: @Rarst, yes after skip importing media, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal experience this is network/hosting issue with original images used, which are hosted (and CDNed) by wordpress com. I had never had it bad enough to break import, but I had errors with importing them on multiple occasions.

Possible solutions:

- the issue comes and goes, import on another day (sounds silly, but least effort :)
- increase PHP execution time limit
- filter `http_request_timeout` to reduce network timeout wait time (defaults to 5 seconds)

Note that even without errors there are several megabytes worth of them and on slow enough connection it can be sizable to download in short time.